# Spring 4 + Hibernate 5.1 Transaction auto committed after call another DAO query

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions, atomikos

I have a problem with transaction auto committed after call another dao native query.

Both service and dao signed as @Transactional.

What am I doing wrong here?

Spring 4.2.x

Hibernate 5.1.0

Atomikos 3.9.3

This is my setup:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="jtaPlatformAdapter" class="com.xxx.JtaPlatformAdapter">
    <property name="jtaTransactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager" destroy-method="close" id="atomikosTransactionManager" init-method="init">
    <property name="forceShutdown" value="true" />
    <property name="startupTransactionService" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp" id="atomikosUserTransaction" />

<bean class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="atomikosTransactionManager" />
    <property name="userTransaction" ref="atomikosUserTransaction" />
</bean>


<bean id="datasouce" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    ...
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" id="JPAVendorAdapter">
    ...
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="emf" depends-on="transactionManager,jtaPlatformAdapter">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.xxx.server"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasouce" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="pun" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="JPAVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="on_close" />
            <entry key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="com.xxx.server.JtaPlatformAdapter" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="pun" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

service

```
@Transactional
@Scope("prototype")
public synchronized void save(EntityObj model) throws Exception {
    model.setX(30);
    model.setY(40);

    EntityObj oldModel = entityObjDAO.findById(model.getId());
    // after call findById, the model had been commit to DB
    ...
    ...
    ...

    entityObjDAO.store(model); // this will call entityManager.merge(model)
    entityObjDAO.flush();
}
```

DAO

```
@Transactional
public EntityObj findById(String id) {
    EntityObj model = null;
    String sql = "select id,x,y from EntityObj where id = :id"; // this is a native sql query

    Query query = this.entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);
    query.setParameter("id", id);
    Object[] rs = (Object[]) query.getSingleResult();
    if (rs != null) {
      model = new EntityObj();
      model.setId(id);
      model.setX(rs[1] == null ? null : (Integer) rs[1]);
      model.setY(rs[2] == null ? null : (Integer) rs[2]);
    }

  return model;
}
```

thanks!

Comment: pls more informations, more code :)

Comment: @dit I added code of Service and DAO. Thanks.

Comment: ok, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: when the dao execute native sql query, transaction will be committed.
But I need the old object to compare to the new object.
Before Hibernate 4.2 upgrade to 5.1, transaction won't auto commit when the query execute.
Any configuration wrong in Spring, Hibernate or Atomikos?

PS.My English is pretty basic, please don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `@Transactional` in your code, Spring creates a proxy object for your Dao object (wrapper).

So it looks like this if your application is running:

```
public EntityObj proxyMethodForFindById(String id) {

    try {
        // 1. start transaction
        startTransaction();

        // 2. execute your code
        return yourDaoObject.findById(id);

    } finally { // [!] PSEUDO CODE: NO EXCEPTION HANDLING

        // commit transaction
        commitTransaction();
    }

}
```

---

So what happens in your code?

Your save method is marked also as `@Transactional`. So if you are changing your object by setting:

```
model.setX(30);
model.setY(40);
```

Spring creates two proxies. One for `Service` and one four your `Dao`. On the End of the `findById`-Transaction this changes will be commited. Nested transactions is the keyword.

You should remove `@Transaction` in your `findById`-Method or better in the whole Dao object. `Service` should be transactional, not Dao-layer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I remove @Transactional from method and class, but transaction still committed after execute query.

Comment: @T.SET yes, it is because you are getting the same ´touched´ object. So It could be not commit this is just change you made above.